# Python Timestamps Differing on App Engine Python 2.5 / 2.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, python-2.5

Python datetime.fromtimestamp returns a different value on App Engine Python 2.5 vs 2.7.

http://shell.appspot.com/

```
Google App Engine/1.6.6
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, May 17 2011, 11:51:03) 
[GCC 4.3.1]

>>> import datetime
>>> print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(4102444800)
2100-01-01 00:00:00
```

http://shell-27.appspot.com/

```
Google App Engine/1.6.6
Python 2.7.2 (default, Dec 14 2011, 14:36:31) 
[GCC 4.4.3]

>>> import datetime
>>> print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(4102444800)
1963-11-25 17:31:44
```

The 2.5 instance is returning the desired value.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.5:

```
Google App Engine/1.6.6
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, May 17 2011, 11:51:03) 
[GCC 4.3.1]

>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint
9223372036854775807
```

2.7:

```
Google App Engine/1.6.6
Python 2.7.2 (default, Dec 14 2011, 14:36:31) 
[GCC 4.4.3]

>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint
2147483647
```

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like a workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588027/converting-timestamps-larger-than-maxint-into-datetime-objects)